# SOAPpy installation error

Tags: soappy

Hi i was trying to install SOAPpy module on my mac for python......
i installed xml and fpconst and tried installing this SOAPpy module, but i was getting the error... as below:
venj:SOAPpy-0.12.0 venkata$ python setup.py build

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "setup.py", line 8, in 
    from SOAPpy.version import **version**
  File "/Applications/SOAPpy-0.12.0/SOAPpy/**init**.py", line 5, in 
    from Client      import *
  File "/Applications/SOAPpy-0.12.0/SOAPpy/Client.py", line 46
    from **future** import nested_scopes

SyntaxError: from **future** imports must occur at the beginning of the file

venj:SOAPpy-0.12.0 venkata$ python setup.py install

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 8, in 
    from SOAPpy.version import **version**
  File "/Applications/SOAPpy-0.12.0/SOAPpy/**init**.py", line 5, in 
    from Client      import *
  File "/Applications/SOAPpy-0.12.0/SOAPpy/Client.py", line 46
    from **future** import nested_scopes
SyntaxError: from **future** imports must occur at the beginning of the file

Hey please suggest me how to solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem.

You have to "future import" to the beginning of everyfile where it's stated.

There should be a patch for that.

Comment: Samme issue, manually editing of the Client.py, Types.py and Server.py and moving the 'from __future__ import nested_scopes' line at the beginning solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a bug in SOAP.py from future must be at the beginning of the file [SOAP.py bug](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1932300&group_id=26590&atid=387667) see [python language docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement)